# Quicktabs- Drupal7

Tags: views, blocks

I am newbie to Drupal and just started building website in Drupal-7.

I have created Three Tables Block using View. And I have created tabs using Quicktabs Module. But Tab title displayed as HTML source code in Quicktabs.

Can anyone please help me with that? Or is there any other way to create block that shows tabular data dynamically with tabs on the top?

I have also tried to create view tabs. But it create page with menu tabs and I want a tabular blocks(three different blocks) with tab.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your QuickTabs instance, try changing the ajax from yes to no.

Ajax-

Yes: Load only the first tab on page view

**No: Load all tabs on page view.**